# Storing sessions in encrypted cookies

Tags: security, http, session, authentication, cookies

Is it a good idea to store sessions on a client side using encrypted cookies with an HMAC?

There is a problem: if somebody discovers a secret key, they could gain access to any user account. Could this problem be eliminated by attaching a part of user's password hash to a cookie? Then on the server side, you could compare this hash to the actual value.

Comment: Hey, I took some liberties with the wording of your question. Please make sure you still feel like it represents what you were asking. If not, please roll back. I was just trying to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use the password hash for anything other than verifying a user's credentials. Not sure if you were implying otherwise, but you definitely do not want to leak hashes (partial or otherwise) for no reason.

You are exactly right that encryption + HMAC can be broken if a malicious user discovers the key(s). That is why we must guard the keys with extreme care. It is all but impossible for a malicious user to be able to determine the key from a properly encrypted cypher.

To get your keys, they would have to compromise your server. If they can compromise your server, none of this really matters. All your proposal would do is to make them have to get two keys instead of just one. They have access to your encryption keys, so they likely have access to your database... so the hashes are already exposed. It's like adding a moat after someone is already in your castle.

In short, encryption + hmac is not broken. It is sufficient for protecting your cookie assume you have properly implemented it.

Comment: But if malicious user have access to my DB, nothing would help me.

Comment: That's true. That's exactly my point. You can't design your system as if the enemy has your keys. Those **have** to be secret. You kind of have to trust the encryption + have good policies about changing keys/audits/etc.